# How to get product using price range magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get products using  price range suppose we i want product with price range of

**50-500** then how can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=>$from,'to'=>$to));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('price',array('from' => '50','to' => '500'))->getData();

    $productId = array();
    foreach($model as $key => $val) {
        foreach($val as $v) {
             $productId[$key] = $val['entity_id'];
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
->addAttributeToFilter('price', array(array('from'=>'0','to'=>'5000'), array('from'=>'15000','to'=>'20000')) )
```