# Programmatically get all products which price greater than 15000INR and assign to category in Admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7, category, products, admin-panel

I have to get all products which **price is greater than 15000INR and assign those products into specific category in Admin panel** programmatically.

Looking forward this answer.

Answer (score 0):

- To get collection of products on the basis of price range follow this link [How to get product using price range magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134678/how-to-get-product-using-price-range-magento)

*To assign this collection to the category use the following code example (I assume your category id is 1509, just for example

```
foreach($collection as $prd){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prd->getId()); $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); $categories[] = 1509;$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
             $product->save();}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Its not working.

Comment: I have tried below :

`$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('price',array('from' => '1000','to' => '10000'))->getData();

   $productId = array();
   foreach($model as $key => $val) {
      foreach($val as $v) {
             $productId[$key] = $val['entity_id'];
        } }
foreach($productId as $prd){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prd->getId()); 
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); 
    $categories[] = 11;
   $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
   $product->save();
}
`